# Module automatically adding namespace to a method being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, rubygems

I'm trying to create a gem, my gem requires a different gem that I have added into the gemspec.

My issue is when I try to call a method inside the code, ruby automatically adds the module namespace to the method I am calling, then I get an uninitialized constant error.  I put a basic example of what is going on below.

lib/example_gem.rb

```
module FooModule

  def bar
    # this is the method I am trying to run
    BAZ::Request.execute(123)
  end
end

class Test
  include FooModule    
end

x = Test.new
x.bar

=>>>>>>>> uninitialized constant FooModule::Baz (NameError)
```

I'm not trying to call FooModule::Baz, I want to call BAZ::Request.execute(123).  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
::BAZ::Request.execute(123)
```

The keyword is "constant lookup operator". I assume `BAZ` isn't wrapped into another class or module, so you need to look for it on the topmost level. Therefore you prepend `::`.

And now you understand why the request (`BAZ::Request`) needs to be within `BAZ`.

Comment: this worked for me too. but is there an elegant way of solving it? should I add my class on a module? @guitarman